# why would local web url change after deleting and restoring files

Tags: url, easyphp

I use EasyPHP and DevServer on Windows10 and today I inadvertently deleted the content of my localweb c:\localweb after unfaintaining/headbeating/swearing  I got most of my files back from the Recycle Bin but found that links weren't working and I couldn't get stuff to work eventually found that the location for localweb has changed a bit.

I used to use a url like http://127.0.0.1/edsa-localweb/x_hello_world.php and the php would work just fine but now I have to use http://127.0.0.1:8000/edsa-localweb/x_hello_world.php

Anyone got any idea how to get rid of the need for the :8000 and why this might have happened?  I can't see why deleting files and then recovering them would make any difference whatsoever.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `:8000` is a [Port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)). You have to use it, because you are not allowed (unless you reached higher privileges) to open ports under numer 1024, for security reasons.
So if it worked for you in the first place (which I doubt), then you have to use IIS or admin rights to start your devserver.

Also, please note, that it is good practice for a web developer to be able to reach your page with any port or domain programmed, so hard coded domains or ports is a bad programming style.

Comment: Thanks I guess.  

As the Webserver is serving no one but me and will never be made public security is not an issue.  To reiterate   I used to use a url like http://127.0.0.1/edsa-localweb/x_hello_world.php and the php would work just fine but now I have to use http://127.0.0.1:8000/edsa-localweb/x_hello_world.php .

Comment: Is that an issue? Otherwise do the things I stated, run your devserver as root or use IIS as a proxy.

Comment: as to the best of my knowledge I did not run the devserver as root in the first place I am still trying to understand what changed

Comment: I guess a missing config file for your devserver. Stop worrying about that ;) Focus on programming

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to explain why my URL changed after deleting all of the files in c:\localweb, however after some playing around was able to return my environment back to what it had been, that is URLs without port numbers.  The dev server was being run as administrator.

The fix:

. Delete C:\Program Files . (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17

. run EasyPHP-Devserver-17.0-setup.exe

. start DevServer  ( with properties X run as Administrator )

. Open Dashboard

. Add localweb C:\localweb

. Start servers

PHP server now running

after reinstallation

C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\httpserver\apache2425vc11x86x180802194151\conf\httpd.conf  has a couple of entries for 127.0.0.1:80

C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\httpserver\apache2425vc11x86x180802194151\conf\httpd-alias.conf has an entry for 127.0.0.1

Prior to reinstall httpd.conf had entries for 127.0.0.1:8000 but I found editing those values to 127.0.0.1 had no good effect it could not get the url to load regardless of port number 80 8000 or zilch.

I had not checked the value in httpd-alias.conf prior to reinstall - so it may have been an issue .

Following reinstall URL in the form http://127.0.0.1/edsa-localweb/x_hello_world.php work again, A port number is NOT required, at least not when working on the PC running the server and there is envisaged no external access.

I thought that the reinstall may have created a config file in the localweb directory that I had inadvertently deleted but there does not appear to be one, yet the behaviour of the DevServer is back to what it was before I deleted the files in localweb.

This arrangement of no port, may not be ideal, but it works for me.